# What is the syntax for conditionals in Solaris 10 Makefiles?

Tags: makefile, solaris, conditional-statements

I'm forced to use `/usr/ccs/bin/make` in Solaris 10 (SunOS 5.10).

The typical GNU `make` syntax for `ifeq`, which can be used to include or exclude text, doesn't work with Solaris `make`.

I can use `sh` style `if` statements when assigning values to macros, but I'm looking for a way to include or exclude a bunch of text in the makefile based off on an environment variable (like with GNU's `ifeq`).

Any ideas? I'd also appreciate any documentation on Solaris 10's version of `make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris `make` is a moderately complex beastie, but it is not GNU Make.

AFAIK, it does not use conditionals.

It does have conditional macros `:=` and incremental macros `+=`.

Comment: I couldn't find examples of conditionals, hence this question. Does your answer mean that what I'm trying to do is not possible using Solaris' make?

Comment: `ifeq` conditionals are a non-standard GNU Make extension.  Other versions of make do not have (all the) GNU make extensions in place. Yes; what you are trying to do is not possible using the syntax you are trying to use. There may be other ways to achieve the same thing, but you can't do it the same as with GNU make. (This is the downside of using extensions; you get locked into the particular implementation of whatever provides the extensions. Lock-in is just as real with open source as with proprietary; it is just, usually, less painful than proprietary lock-in because you have the source.)

Answer (score 2):

The online documentation is also available here:

[man pages section 1: User Commands](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9l0/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that. (Getting to the online man pages from the main oracle documentation page is not immediately obvious.)

Comment: Indeed, I was referring to the online manual page which is the immediately obvious place to look. The link was there just in case you didn't install it.